# bodyparser to parse gzip and json both type of HTTP POST request bodies

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-post, body-parser

I have created an API end point to handle http POST requests from a client.
Currently Express framework and bodyParser to handle the request bodies. How do I use the body-parser to take care of cases where request bodies that may either be gzipped compressed Json objects OR plain Json objects.

bodyParser json parser will only handle requests when the Content-Type in request header and type below are both same.

```
bodyParser.json({type: 'application/gzip'}) 

bodyParser.json({type: 'application/json'})
```

Is there a way bodyParser can handle both cases in the API end point ?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, no worries
I am able to figure out how will that happen.
I can have bodyParser handle both the gzip and json POST payload bodies.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/gzip'}))
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/json'}))
```

The first parser will handle if `Content-Type` in request header is  `application/gzip`

The second will handle if  if `Content-Type` in request header is  `application/json`

Answer (score 0):

For me following worked:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: ['application/json', 'application/gzip']}))
```